# How to make larger stars have a _longer_ lifespan?

Tags: alternate-reality

What if in an parallel universe, the bigger the mass of the star, the bigger lifespan lasts for a very long time. For example, living for trillion of years if not longer. How would this work and why?

Comment: Are you asking about the lifespan of the star itself?

Comment: Can you allow for the basic laws of physics to be slightly different? If the gravitational constant is slightly different, or the force of gravity is inversely proportional to the cube of the distance (instead of distance squared) it might be possible for that to happen.

Comment: A star's mass DOES directly affect its lifespan, although in just the opposite way that you want.  The more massive the star, the shorter its life.

Answer (score 5):

You need some feedback mechanism that *reduces* the reaction rate at high pressure.

[*Understand*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution) why massive stars burn hotter by reaching an equilibrium point.  How can you break this, without messing up all of physics?

Perhaps another particle that interferes with the fusion process, whose effect increases faster with pressure and temperature.

Fusion might require a specific resonance that centers atound a specific energy.  Look at how [pebble bed reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebble-bed_reactor) are engineered: raising the temperature makes them *slow down the reaction*, so it centers at a constant temperature.

> When the nuclear fuel increases in temperature, the rapid motion of the atoms in the fuel causes an effect known as Doppler broadening. The fuel then sees a wider range of relative neutron speeds. Uranium-238, which forms the bulk of the uranium in the reactor, is much more likely to absorb fast or epithermal neutrons at higher temperatures. This reduces the number of neutrons available to cause fission, and reduces the power of the reactor. Doppler broadening therefore creates a negative feedback because **as fuel temperature increases, reactor power decreases**.

Cool it effectively and it puts out more.  In a bigger pile (star) the surface area is smaller relative to the volume, so it cools less.

Come up with a similar kind of *negative* feedback for the mechanisms involved in stellar fusion.

Comment: Maybe larger, heavier stars attract more dark matter, which in this parallel universe slows down fusion a bit?  Too much dark matter and a star would just go out.

Comment: Well done, sir, a nice speculative mechanism to make more massive stars last longer. If the resonance has its optimal / maximal operation at lower temperatures or pressures, then low mass stars will burn faster and high mass ones slower. This answer made me smile with its conceptual daring and creativity. Plus one (and wishing I could award more).